# how to use web3j over infura to find exact gas price used for a successful transaction

Tags: web3j, gas-price

my goal is to compute the cost of gas for a successful tx.
I get a callback when a transaction succeeds and i retrieve `gasUsed` with
`transactionReceipt.getGasUsed()`. Now I need to know the exact gas price that was used for this tx.

It does not seem like gasprice is stored in txreceipt. the gas price (obtained with `transfer.requestCurrentGasPrice()`) is in some other place where tx is signed but at that time we would not know the actual gas that will be used. so i wait for `txreceipt` to find the actual gas used but i then ran into the issue of not knowing gas price that was used.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to call [`web3.eth.getTransactionByHash()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionbyhash) using the transaction hash once you've received your callback.

The returned data includes:

```
...
gas: QUANTITY - gas provided by the sender.
gasPrice: QUANTITY - gas price provided by the sender in Wei.
...
```

Comment: The question says `web3j`, however there are similar methods, like `web3j.ethGetTransactionByHash`etc